# How to write any Unicode Key without Pre-programmed key for it in kbd?

Tags: vim, x11, unicode

I am trying to find some Unix tool to input any Unicode key. I am fine with X application or console but I use Vi/m and it may have this property. For example, suppose I want to input key `"U+0303"` or the key `"U+007E"` in Unicode.

You should get something below, [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde), with the unicodes:

```
U+0303 ◌̃ combining tilde and U+007E ~
```

I am looking for a general tool, not be depended on certain kbd layouts. It is actually better if it is was some very basic tool without unnecessary bells-and-whistles. The simplest win.

Comment: If nothing else is present, entering `javascript:document.write("&#x7e;");` into a browser's empty tab gives you something to copy-and-paste. Far from comfortable, but these days, you'll hardly ever be without browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **[GTK+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_Linux) applications** you can simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, type in the hex and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> → `~`

This works in my Vim. For the **[native Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#In_platform_independent_applications)** combination:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Escape</kbd> → `~`; cursor on top of the key